# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost only when WIFI is connected

Tags: macos, unix, ionic-framework, localhost

I'm experiencing the weirdest issue, I just spent an hour with Apple Support and still no resolution. When I try to access localhost while on WIFI it says server not found, when i try to run my ionic app in "serve" mode it errors in the console ENOTFOUND localhost. However when I am on Ethernet without wifi it works fine... Ethernet with wifi also is broken. Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: Turned out it was a host file issue...

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in my host file. Solved